# .in'ig.status: error: cannot find input file: `Makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I'm new to GNU and I've been trying to compile a package using Autotools on Mac. After executing the command `./configure`, I get the following:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0 file names to x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0 format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for lipo... lipo
checking for otool... otool
checking for otool64... no
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking for -force_load linker flag... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin19.4.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for math... no
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking sys/utsname.h usability... yes
checking sys/utsname.h presence... yes
checking for sys/utsname.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking windows.h usability... no
checking windows.h presence... no
checking for windows.h... no
checking gmp.h usability... yes
checking gmp.h presence... yes
checking for gmp.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for long long... yes
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking for uint8_t... yes
checking for random... yes
checking for erf... yes
checking for lgamma... yes
checking for log1p... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
.in'ig.status: error: cannot find input file: `Makefile
```

After speaking with a teammate working on Windows and using MinGW64, the issue arises on the last line, where the Makefile is supposed to be created like so:

```
config.status: creating Makefile
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe some files in your system should have been converted from using Windows line endings CRNL to using POSIX line endings NL?  The extra CR character is causing the cursor to go back to the beginning of the line without a newline, and it's causing the name of your file to be MakefileCR (or, `Makefile\r`) rather than just Makefile.  Obviously the file named `Makefile\r.in` does not exist.

Comment: After looking more carefully at the configure.ac file, it was indeed a line ending that was causing the error! Thanks much :)

Comment: Please accept answers if they answer your question, so others know they're complete, thanks!

Comment: This is going to become more common since WSL (and WSL2) is now getting more and more popular

Comment: It would be good if someone could figure out which tools are doing the wrong thing.  Make itself is not involved in this (as best as I can tell).  GNU make has accepted both line endings in makefiles since version 3.78 (released in 1999).  Maybe it's automake, or whatever tool automake uses?  For packages that use automake files (`Makefile.am`) it's automake that will create the `Makefile.in` file.  However, it's a little hard to understand how automake would convert `Makefile.am\r\n` into `Makefile\r.in`... ?

Answer (score 4):

Using @MadScientist's answer, the complete solution for me (using Ubuntu 16.04 on WSL) was -

```
$autoconf
$./configure --> throws the above error
$ dos2unix configure.ac
$autoconf
$./configure --> No issue now
```

`cat -e <filename>` will also show you the line endings to confirm.

Comment: it is not success in my machine